# Not Sure why my Google App Script is sometimes returning "undefined"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a script that looks at a string and if it contains a defined word or phrase it returns the appropriate Google Shopping Category.  However, sometimes my function returns "undefined" and I am not really sure why.

I have one sheet that holds all the different Google Shopping Categories I use and another sheet where I put my data for the function to analyze.

Here is an example of a value that is returning "undefined":

Text that is being analyzed: **Wall Hangings>Artwork & Prints**

returned value: **undefined**

My code:

```
//places the correct GS Category for specific item in column E:E
function placement() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('GSData');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (i =1 ; i < values.length ; i++) {
    //checks to see if the cell is blank if it is blank it runs it through the category();
    if (values[i][4] === ""){      
      var gsCategory = category(values[i][3]);
      sheet.getRange(i+1,5).setValue(gsCategory);
    }
  }

  //checks the phrase and the finds the best suitable Category for the product
  function category(x) {
    //pulls in the Sheet data and sets it equal to the "cat" variable.
    var cat = categoryData();
    //search functions can be found on the search.gs file
    //find specific keywords in the phrase then return the correct corresponding GS category
    if(searchTowels(x)){
      return cat[76];
    }else if(searchWallHanging(x)){
      Logger.log(cat[39]);
      return cat[39];
    }else if(searchWesterDecor(x)){
      return cat[37];
    }else if(searchLamps(x)){
      return cat[66];
    }
  }
}

function categoryData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('GSCategories');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return values;
}

function rawData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('GSData');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return values;
}
```

I wrote out tons of more else if statements to cover all the different categories I have products for.  However, I didn't want to paste them all due to all the space they would take up.

The Search Function:

```
function searchWallHanging(x) {
  if(x.search("Wall Hangings") > 0){
    return true; 
  }else {
    return false; 
  }
```

I just included the one search function to save space.

Comment: This is just a guess, but could it be due to spaces on either side of the string or extra spaces between words? This is unnoticeable and can cause huge problems.  For example, " string" != "string". It's best to normalize strings before comparison by calling trim() and toLowerCase(). But that won't help if you have extra spaces between words. To me, "Wall Hangings" seems like a bad pattern to follow for category name. Using lowercase words with underscores or dashes would make strings much easier to compare.

Comment: you should also familiarize and use the debugger to step into code and figure out where your bug lives.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it is just looking for "Wall Hangings", so it shouldn't matter if their are spaces before or after the trigger word "Wall Hangings", right?  However, if their was a extra space in the word or something like that, then that would cause a problem.

Comment: @ZigMandel I tried using it.  However, it didn't really help me figure out what was triggering the "undefined" return value.  That being said there is a good chance I didn't use it correctly.  I am new to Google App Scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on the `search()` return values. There is an obvious mistake there

```
function searchWallHanging(x) {
  if(x.search("Wall Hangings") > 0){
    return true; 
  }else {
    return false; 
}
```

I will give you 3 strings and what it will return

1. `Purple Wall Hangings` — returns **TRUE**
2. `Green Dress Robes` — returns **FALSE**
3. `Wall Hangings Galore` — returns **undefined**

The secret lies in this bit: `x.search("Wall Hangings") > 0` as `search()` will return the **first** match. So in our example #3 because it begins with our query string, we get `x.search("Wall Hangings") == 0` which is **not** `> 0`. Easy fix:

```
function searchWallHanging(x) {
  if(x.search("Wall Hangings") >= 0){
    return true; 
  }else {
    return false; 
}
```

**EDIT:** oh yes, and this applies to all similar searches. If all of your functions look like the one above, then you are not utilising the functions to their full usefulness. The idea is to never write similar blocks of code so you may wish to rethink how that particular bit works between different categories.

Comment: I totally agree and I don't think I am utilizing the functions to their full usefulness.  This was just the only way I knew how to solve the problem.  I will be going back over this to try and figure out a more effective way of accomplishing the same thing. That being said thank you very much for your help and pointing out my mistake.